# How to re-define what 1px is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change **all elements with length unit** (including width, margin, padding, font-size, etc.) using the definition of **1px = 0.1vh**.

For example, `font-size: 15px` will then be `font-size: 1.5vh`

Is there a way I can achieve my goal using javascript or jquery?

---

Please use https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html as a minimal reproducible example

Comment: you could define a font-size on HTML via vh, then use rem units every where else to use it as a reference. Else you'll need a javascript blender to cook this up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's a hacky way I just cooked up:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");

elements.forEach((element) => {
  const fontSize = getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("font-size");
  if (fontSize.endsWith("px")) {
    let px = Number(fontSize.replace("px", ""));
    if (px === parseInt(px)) {
      let vh = px / 10;
      element.style.fontSize = `${vh}vh`;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My goal is changing **all elements with length unit** (including width, margin, padding, font-size, etc.), is there a way we don't specify font-size?